# does docker rmi remove images from storage backend

Tags: docker, azure-blob-storage, docker-registry

I am using Azure Storage backend for my private docker repository. I want to free up local disk space and this is command I wish to execute.

`docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)`

I want to know, will this command delete the images on local system or will it also delete the images stored on the storage backend?

Comment: This will delete only local images, and this is still very hard to delete images from a docker registry... you won't be able to delete everything easily ;)

Comment: Thanks I was quite skeptical :)